# SEO Url for Profiles

Tags: .htaccess

## Preface

I'm trying to re-write a URL for a profile page.  All of my application pages have a `.html` extension, so I'm trying to match just letters, numbers, `-`, and `.`.

So these would be valid

```
site.com/steve
site.com/steve-robbins
site.com/steve.robbins
```

But these wouldn't be

```
site.com/steve.html
site.com/steve-robbins.php
```

Assume I have a check in place so that custom URLs don't have `.html` or `.php` on the end.

## Problem

I'm currently using this but it's not working

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+)$ profile.php?url=$1 [L]
```

It should set `url` to `steve`, but it's setting it to `profile.php`

What am I doing wrong?

---

My complete `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

#
#   LOGIN
#
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{255})/activate\.html$ login.php?activate=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^logout\.html$ login.php?logout [L]

#
#   SETTINGS
#
RewriteRule ^change-([a-z]+)\.html$ account-settings.php?$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+)$ profile.php?url=$1 [L]

# SEO friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)\.php$ $1.html [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of your rules (under the `RewriteBase /` directive):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

That should stop it from looping. The rewrite engine will keep re-applying all the rules until the URI going in (sans query string) is the same as the URI that comes out of the rules. That's why the value of `url` is `profile.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a leading slash to the redirect like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)$ /profile.php?url=$1 [L]
```

The reason you're getting a `url` value of `profile.php` is because the `[L]` flag is kinda misleading when it comes to the `.htaccess` file. In the server config files it does exactly what you'd think, but in the `.htaccess` file it stops reading rules at that rule, but then goes through the rules again until path is unchanged by any of the rules. By adding the leading `/`, your rule will not match the second time around as you exclude `/` from the regex. I spent a while struggling with this *feature* myself.

Comment: Causes `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: I think `RewriteBase /` might be the culprit in that case. Could you try commenting out that line and adding leading slashes to your redirect urls?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of a beginner in interpreting mod_rewrite rules but if I understand it correctly your rule is matched and than matched again, either add something to the url matching scheme like /profile/user or add a condition to not redirect if already redirected